# WebClient & Final Callback

Tags: multithreading, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have several threads in my application that are making WebClient calls. I need to know when they are all done whether they complete, error out, terminate prematurely, etc. The problem is that the Done callback does not always get called, especially after the Error callback is finished. Also, the Response or Done callback can encounter an error and not complete. And the WebClient can potentially not  succeed at all and error out even before Response or Done complete.  How do I know when they are all done so I can perform actions, such as cleanup recourses. Is there another type of callback (such as finally) that always gets called?

```
// Main thread
public class DoWork1 implements Runnable {
    
    @override
    public void run() {
    
        // Setup client.

        // Call service.
        Mono<String> response1 = client1.post();
        response1.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), new 
            MyDoneCallback()); 

        // Do work

        // After all threads are done, clean up resources.
    }
}

// Second thread
public class DoWork2 implements Runnable {
    
    @override
    public void run() {
    
        // Setup client.

        // Call service.
        Mono<String> response2 = client2.post();
        response2.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), new 
            MyDoneCallback()); 

        // Do work.
    }
}

// Third thread
public class DoWork3 implements Runnable {
    
    @override
    public void run() {
    
        // Setup client.

        // Call service.
        Mono<String> response3 = client3.post();
        response1.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), new 
            MyDoneCallback()); 

        // Do work.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WebClient is asynchronous, so you either call `Mono.block` on separate threads and work in synchronous paradigm, or call `subscribe` in a single thread and handle result by provided callbacks.

In the first case I suggest you define a thread pool/executor, submit tasks that call `.block` to it, obtain Future and do whatever you want. For example, call `.get` on each under try-finally block.

In the second case, call WebClient in the single thread, obtain all Monos and deal with them. For example, you can merge them into a `Flux`, wait until all finished synchronously:

```
    Mono<String> response1Mono = client.post().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    Mono<String> response2Mono = client.post().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    Mono<String> response3Mono = client.post().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);

    try {
        List<String> allResponses = Flux.merge(response1Mono, response2Mono, response3Mono)
                .collectList()
                .block();
    } finally {
        // clean up
    }
```

Or do it in completely asynchronous manner:

```
    Flux.merge(response1Mono, response2Mono, response3Mono)
            .subscribe(new OnEachResponseCallbcak(), new OnErrorCallback(), new OnCompleteCallback());
```

One of `OnErrorCallback` and `OnCompleteCallback` will eventually be called. Probably from other thread, here is a quote from `subscribe` javadoc:

> Keep in mind that since the sequence can be asynchronous, this will
> immediately return control to the calling thread. This can give the
> impression the consumers are not invoked when executing in a main
> thread or a unit test for instance

Comment: This solution ended up not working. It does not wait until all callbacks are done processing, such as having the MyDonecallbacks completed. Instead, it just waits until WebClinet gets a response.

Comment: Which of 3 approaches have you implemented? If you picked up the last one, you have await callback to be called manually. Just providing them to subscribe obviously doesn't make it block until they are called

Comment: The second one. I need to wait until all callbacks are finished. Any ideas?

Comment: The second one is `collectList().block()` and 1) there is no callback here 2) it will definitely wait until requests are performed, otherwise what objects will list contain?

Comment: But when I created the WebClient calls, I registered the response, error and done callbacks and that created the Monos. See the code above  or here: 
      // Call service.
        Mono<String> response1 = client1.post();
        response1.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), new 
            MyDoneCallback()); 

Your code waits/blocks until all Monos get their WebClient response. But my problem is waiting until all Mono's callbacks  (response, error, done) have finished processing their response data. How do I solve that?

Comment: If you do `response1.subscribe` you do not follow any of my recipes. Anyway, if you want to wait until callback is called you have to write some concurrency code with locks/conditions or whatever. Its better to just use approach 2: `Flux.merge(response1Mono, response2Mono, response3Mono).collectList().block();` and there is no `subscribe` and callbacks here